# preserve incoming request order in multithreaded api and process in order

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, synchronization, ipc

suppose there is multithreaded API which is reads request from input queue, process the request and then write the data on the output queue.

However there is a constraint : Result of All the incoming request should be written to O/P queue in the same order as it is received.

Example :
Request : [r1, r2 , r3]
Output should be in same order : [o1, o2, o3]

Question : how to synchronise the threads so that all data in output queue maintain order like input queue??

I gave 3 answer to interviewer :

1st Answer :
suppose  threads [t1, t2, t3] handling the incoming request [r1,r2,r3]

we can have join in that case :
t2 join t1
t3 join t2 
that way processing order can be maintained.

Issue with above solution : 
1. Have to create new thread for every request.
2. A thread have to exit after processing and writing the output.

Clearly above solution is not feasible, because what if there is a thread pool and  we have finite number of threads.

2nd Solution :
Lock the output queue when a request is taken by a thread from the input queue.
thread t1 take r1 and mutex lock on output queue.
obviously t2 and t3 wont be able to process request r2 and r3.

Issue with above solution :
1. no concurrency can be achieved in this.
2. a single thread can only process single request.
3. Thread pool concept can not be applied here.

3rd Solution :
We can maintain the order of the request in global data structure.

thread t1 take r1 and add priority p1 in data structure.
data structure : [p1]

thread t2 take r1 and add p2 in priority data structure
data structure : [p1, p2]

now suppose thread t2 finished processing of r2 and willing to write output o2 in O/P queue. t2 will check the data structure and will find that first element in p1 which is not the same as what t2 entered in priority data structure. So t2 will go on finite time of wait and check again.

meanwhile t1 finished now and willing to write output o1 to O/P queue. It checks the data structure and find that first element is p1 which was inserted by t1 itself. so t1 will write the output queue and will remove p1 from global priority data structure.

Please note:
[Global priority data structure can be made thread safe using mutex lock and other mechanism. question is different here :) ]

I have given above answers to interviewer and of which I think my 3rd answer is correct.

But the interviewer does not seems to be pleased with my answers.

Can anyone please give a correct solution for this problem?

Based on the answers given I would like to add few more details:

1) Main thread is not responsible to writing data to output queue. Each thread will write the O/P queue with result
2)A single thread might process more then one request in consecutive manner.
Eg:
Thread T1 process request R1 then Thread T2 process request R2 then Thread T1 put the output o1 in O/P queue and pick another request R3 from the I/P queue to process.
so now Thread T1 processing R3 and Thread T2 is processing R2 request.

3) Also there can be many clients writing request to I/P queue. Its not the clients who are putting request in a particular order and priority.
The  priority is set on the basis of First Come First server basis.

Client C1 put R1 request before Another Client C2 put R2 request. 
So output against the R1 request should be written to O/P queue first.

Comment: Tag each request with a sequence number, associate the output with the request's sequence number, hold output in a map using the sequence number as the key, any output for the next sequence number can be emitted until blocked waiting on next sequence output.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd answer is close.

From what you are saying, you always receive the input in order so it is easy enough to assign a priority to each object added to the queue.

Any thread pick up the elements in order, but work on each element may take longer than the next, so the result in the output queue is not given in order. The priority is used to sort them back to the same order they were received in.

The process that reads the output starts with the first priority and waits until the output with that specific priority number is in the queue. Once it is, it gets used up and next time around, we first check whether the next priority is already available and use it up or it's not present and we block until new data appears in the output queue.

As mentioned by Eljay, an `std::map<unsigned long, your-object-ptr>` can be used for the output queue where the `unsigned long` is the priority.

Only *glitch*, the `unsigned long` will, at some point, revert back to 0. Your algorithm should make sure it can handle that special case if it can happen (i.e. your software runs for a very long time or you very quickly and always get a really large number of messages in the queue).

To prove the point with 3 elements, say 3rd is done first, then 1st and finally 2nd, there are the steps

```
Input Queue
[p1, o1]
[p2, o2]
[p3, o3]

3 Threads pick up the objects and start working

Output Queue
-- first incoming result
[p3, o3]     -- main thread still wait for p1

-- second incoming result
[p1, o1]     -- eat this one!
[p3, o3]

-- check for next result, not present, wait
[p3, o3]

-- third incoming result
[p2, o2]     -- eat this one!
[p3, o3]

-- check for next result, present! return immediately
[p3, o3]     -- eat that one, finally
```

The sort on the queue is not mandatory. If you only expect 2 or 3 elements, not sorting them is not going to make a huge difference. If you could get many more, sorting becomes a good optimization as it will read the data faster that way.

---

From the additional information, the constrain is to **add** to output queue in the correct order. Not to obtain the correct order in the output queue. In that case, we do something similar to above, only we prevent adding to the queue unless the next item is allowed to be added to said queue.

So if the queue did not yet receive item `o1` (output 1), then trying to add `o2` or `o3` blocks the current thread until `o1` was added.

From my example above I would have:

```
Output Queue
-- first incoming result is `o3`
-- thread that handled `o3` blocks until `o2` was added to the queue

-- second incoming result is `o1`
[o1]     -- add this one! counter is now on `o2`

-- wake up threads waiting on queue, thread with `o3` goes back to sleep

-- third incoming result is `o2`
[o2]     -- add this one! counter is now on `o3`

-- wake up threads waiting on queue, thread with `o3` is allowed now!
[o3]
```

Either way works. Personally I prefer the other one because it allows threads to work on the next packet immediately since their load was saved in the queue. However, this way is better if you have limited resources and need to make sure that work gets done no matter what (on a system with a heavy load, it may be the only good solution.)

Of course, the "wake up threads waiting on queue" could be optimized to only wake up the thread waiting because `o2` or `o3` can now specifically be added to the queue. It depends how your implementation functions. The easiest is obviously to wake them all and let each thread decide for itself whether has the next object to be saved.

Note that in this case we do not need to a priority, only a counter to know which reply needs to be saved next.

One possible drawback, either way: if a thread decides to not return any output, your algorithm blocks (in either way.)

Comment: I have few more details in the question based on your answer. Please check them. Thanks.

Comment: @user3990393, I accordingly made an update to my answer.